# Mental block on fprintf string termination

Tags: c, c-strings, null-terminated

I am at a total loss with this one. I can't figure out why this isn't working. Simple character array with a NULL terminator - except that when I output it, it doesn't terminate!

```
int file_create(const char *path) {
    //trying to trap situations where the path starts with /.goutputstream
    char path_left_15[16];
    strncpy(path_left_15, path, 15);
    printf("%d\n", strlen("/.goutputstream")+1);
    path_left_15[strlen("/.goutputstream")+1] = '\0'; 
    printf("%d\n", strlen(path_left_15));
    printf("path_left_15: %s\n", path_left_15);
    //continue on...
}
```

This is my output:

```
> 16 

> 16 

>/.goutputstream\B7<random memory stuff>
```

I can't figure out why this isn't terminating correctly. I've tried making the array longer, but I get the same result every time. I'm losing my mind!

Anyone see it? Thanks.

Comment: **f**printf? You're not passing a file pointer.

Comment: `NULL` is a macro that expands to a null *pointer* constant. Presumably you mean "NUL terminator", or better yet "`'\0'` terminator".

Comment: You're right, Kevin. I meant just printf. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of bound from the array. Instead of `path_left_15[strlen("/.goutputstream")+1] = '\0';` try `path_left_15[15] = '\0';`

You will truncate your string but will be safe when printing.

Comment: I knew this would end with me realizing how dumb I can be. Another example of forgetting when to count from 0 and when to start from 1. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, this doesn't truncate my string. By adding the terminator to path_left_15[15], that's the 16 position of my array - exactly where I want it to be. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your array only has 16 elements, bu you're trying to write to the 17th. So that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: I see what you mean. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks.